# How to wrap images/list items in Windows 10 XAML that span multiple rows?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I've been wondering how to achieve this wrappanel effect that Pinterest uses in their app in XAML for UWP. I've tried the winrtxamlroolkit WrapPanel and the Microsoft Toolkit VariableWrapSizeGrid. I'm not sure what else I can try, and I've looked everywhere on here and elsewhere and cannot find a solution. Is there any way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Personally Iike [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.aspx)

Comment: AFAIK there is no such *virtualized* items panel like the one in the middle screenshot. You'd have to make it yourself which will be a pain (the layout logic for the items is easy, but the virtualization may not be so easy).